# reCAPTCHA - Enterprise step by step on how to deploy on a Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha-enterprise

I am trying to deploy a reCAPTCHA Enterprise v3 on my entire Wordpress website, not just a form or login page.

I have the site & secret keys and I understand how to place the code in the head tag of the site but I am un-clear on how to work with the tokens and where to put that code on my website.

I am looking to secure every page and post along with the contact form and payment link.

There is a lot of help out there with using reCAPTCHA on forms and login but very little on securing a complete website.

I am able to use shortcodes to implement the reCPATCHA banner on individual pages/posts but this I know is a very insecure way of doing this. I also know that the site is not being evaluated by reCPATCHA it's basically the equivalent of a security warning sign in front of your house but no systems in place.

Can anyone point to a site showing examples of how to do this with a WordPress website?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-captcha/) from kinsta for further explanation on the steps to deploy reCAPTCHA v3 on WordPress:

1. Install and Activate a WordPress CAPTCHA Plugin
2. Create Your Google reCAPTCHA and Add It to Your Site
3. Configure Your Settings to Protect Key Areas